# An error occurred during the sign in process: Failed to refresh access token

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to connect to an Azure subscription with my personal account. This used to work fine before, but now after I have entered my email address and password, it waits for a while and then displays the following message:

[image]

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: I had this before. I did not get to the bottom of it, but buy signing in again in Visual Studio 2015 (on the same machine), my 2017 started to work again.

Comment: I have tried this, but did not work. I also updated to the latest version of VS2017 but to no avail.
It might have to do with some MFA modifications that were done to our accounts though. We are looking into this now.